# How to write regex to fix words composed of duplicate letters?

Tags: python, regex

I scraped a few pdfs and some thick fonts get scraped as in this example:

```
text='and assesses oouurr rreeffoorrmmeedd tteeaacchhiinngg in the classroom'
```

instead of

```
"and assesses our reformed teaching in the classroom"
```

How to fix this? I am trying with regex

```
pattern=r'([a-z])(?=\1)'
re.sub(pattern,'',text)
#"and aseses reformed teaching in the clasrom"
```

I am thinking of grouping the two groups above and add word boundaries

EDIT: this one fixes words with even number of letters:

```
pattern=r'([a-z])\1([a-z])\2'
re.sub(pattern,'\1\2',text)
#"and assesses oouurr reformed teaching in the classroom"
```

Comment: This will require some NLP library because you cannot just remove all repeated letters

Comment: Pure regex alone can't really figure out that `rreeffoorrmmeedd` should be reduced to `reform`, but `assesses` should _not_ be reduced to `aseses`.  You need a dictionary of some kind here.

Comment: What is your ideal outcome (what level of inaccuracy is acceptable?)

Comment: @Nick It does not have to be perfect, but it should not mess up good words. The more words I correct, the better. In any case I will run NLP and remove all wrong words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If letters are duplicated, you can try something like this

```
for w in text.split():
    if len(w) %2 != 0:
        print(w)
        continue
    if w[0::2] == w[1::2]:
        print(w[0::2])
        continue
    print(w)
```

Comment: nice! what if the string contains separators different than space such as \n?

Comment: `split` default separator is any whitespace

Answer (score 0):

i found solution in javascript that works fine :

```
([a-z])\1(?:(?=([a-z])\2)|(?<=\3([a-z])\1\1))
```

but in some how it doesn't work in python because lookbehind can't take references to group so i came up with another solution that can work in this example :

```
([a-z])\1(?:(?=([a-z])\2)|(?=[^a-z])))
```

try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/yLrB0p/1)

Answer (score 0):

I am using a mixed approach: build the pattern and substitution in a for loop, then applying regex. The regexes applied go from e.g. words of 8x2=16 letters down to 3.

```
import re
text = 'and assesses oouurr rreeffoorrmmeedd tteeaacchhiinngg in the classroom'
wrd_len = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2]
for l in wrd_len:
    sub = '\\' + '\\'.join(map(str,range(1,l+1)))
    pattern = '([a-z])\\' + '([a-z])\\'.join(map(str,range(1,l+1)))
    text = re.sub(pattern, sub , text)
text
#and assesses our reformed teaching in the classroom
```

For example, the regex for 3-letter words becomes:

```
re.sub('([a-z])\1([a-z])\2([a-z])\3', '\1\2\3', text)
```

As a side note, I could not get those backslashes right with raw strings, and I am actually going to use [a-zA-Z].